# Insert Code Into A Variable?

Tags: vba, excel

The code below should create the right picture of what I'm trying to do, which is to insert a code into a variable that can be used later on.

ALSO:

S1 is a String, fixedInterest is a String

```
    S1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    fixedInterest = S1.Range("A1").Value
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just `Dim S1 As Worksheet` and `Set S1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`?

Comment: `fixedInterest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value`

Comment: @Comintern isn't that exactly what I did?

Comment: @Slai Yeah I know that I'm that much of a newbie, I'm trying to organize it because of the ridiculous amount of different sheets im dealing with

Comment: if it makes it any easier, you can also do it this way `fixedInterest = [Sheet1!A1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you want to store the codeline itself(not the value) in a variable so you don't have to use it every time you need that value.

The most feasible way of achieving that would be the creation of a function.

Using your variables:

```
Function S1() as String

    S1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value

End Function
```

In your main code you can then assign the value this function returns to a variable:

```
fixedInterest = S1()
```

Also to clarify: A string variable always only returns a string value. You can't 'convert it back to code'. It can however be used in methods that make us of a string.

e.g.:

```
Dim strName as string

strName = "MyWorkbook"

Workbooks(strName).open
'is the same as
Workbooks("MyWorkbook").open
```

__
Edit:

```
Dim S1 as worksheet

Set S1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

S1.Range("A2").Value= "something"
```

Comment: No no no that's not what I'm going for, I know all that you just explained, I somehow wanna do S1.Range("A1").Value

Comment: Clarify S1 as a worksheet object. Editted my answer.